# Creating json file in Internal Storage and writing on it

Tags: android, json, kotlin, internal-storage

I am trying to create a Jsonfile inside the internal Storage of the App and then writing a jsonarray into it, but somehow it dosent create the file, i know this because i am trying to read it later on but it dosent work. Does anyone know why that is? My code looks like this:

````
fun addJson(){
            val dir = File(this.filesDir, "mydir")
            val json: String?
            try {
                val file =  File(dir,"stempel.json")
                val writer = FileWriter(file)

                val inputStream = assets.open("stempel.json")
                json = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
                val jsonarr = JSONArray(json)

                writer.append(jsonarr.toString())
                writer.flush()
                writer.close()

            } catch (e: Exception){}
        }

```
````

Comment: Also post the code where you try to read the file.

Comment: Donot use an intermediate json array. Just copy the file.

Comment: You should put the normal code in your catch block as now you will not know if it throws.

Comment: `"mydir"` You should check if this subdir exists. And if not create it using mkdir().

Comment: i know the reading works as i have allready tried it with a json that i put in manually

Comment: oh i dont even want to make a subdir, is there a way to create the json without making a subdir